# Python compile a script within a GUI

Tags: python, linux, user-interface, raspberry-pi, python-idle

I am currently working on the final year project for my degree. I have chosen to research and develop a tool to aid the delivery of the new Computing curriculum that is coming to schools next year.

I am using a Raspberry Pi in my development, and I aim to teach extremely basic Python programming to children between the ages of 8 and 10. They are going to be able to control some hardware attached to the Pi using a simple API that I am going to create.

My question is: I would like to be able to create a GUI for the children to work in, which would allow them to write and compile scripts. This is mainly to get away from the unfamiliar interface of Linux and terminals etc, and put them in a friendly, basic interface which will pretty much just allow them to write their code and click a big red button to compile and run it to interact with the hardware. Is it possible to allow for text to be written in a GUI and then compiled when the button is pressed?

I am pretty new to Python myself so I am not as clued up as I'd like to be about the specifics of it. I know that it is possible to have the output of IDLE inside of a tkinter interface, and that it is possible to have text boxes for user input and stuff, but would it actually be possible to compile a script on button press and then run it? I have been thinking that maybe threading is the answer. Perhaps I could create a new thread to do it when the button is pressed?

My apologies if this is incredibly basic, but I am having no luck finding any answers about how I would do this. I think it's mainly because I am unsure on what exactly to ask for.

I appreciate any feedback/help, thank you very much.

Dell

Comment: As python doesn't really 'compile' it's confusing to know what you mean. If all you want is a button to run a script you could always have a text box that when you press a button the text contained is saved to disk and ran you could indeed do that with a tk inter or pyside ui then run the file using the subprocess module. Of course there are many ide's that already do the same thing

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply. I am not sure what I was thinking when I wrote about it being compiled, I know it does not compile I was being an idiot...

That sounds like something that would probably work for this. I wanted to get them away from an IDE I think, even though that would be a easier solution. I sort of wanted a bespoke interface instead.

Since the script they are going to write will just be stuff to interact with input and output of hardware I have a feeling what you suggested should do the trick though. (edit edit edit...I think I am lost myself still to be honest >_<)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have your GUi write the Python code to a file, then dynamically import using the imp module. I actually do something similar :-)

```
import imp
hest  = imp.load_source("Name", Path)
```

Comment: This sounds like it would be the way I should go about doing this, as I really want my own sort of environment for them to program in. I am unfamiliar with dynamic importing of modules, however I will hopefully be able to figure it out. I appreciate the help. :)

Comment: I was nervous as well :-). But its quite straight forward. It will be imported just like all other imports . Ping me if it gives you trouble.